# JQuery Post wrong reaction

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, post

I want to post an variable to a PHP-File with This:

```
     $.post( $("#executiveForm").attr("action") ,{id:idvalue},function(response){
        if(response.message === "error"){
            alert("Error");
        }else if(response.message === "okay"){
            location.reload();
        }else{
            alert(response.message);// always undefined
        }
    });
```

My Problem is, that the Parameter is sent to the PHP-File, but my PHP-File didn't respond. I've added the following Code at the first Line in the PHP-File to get an Error back (To test if the Post reachs the PHP-File):

```
$makeItFail = "";
echo $makeItFail.error.showMeSomeErrors;
```

Unfortunately, I only got the respond of my Whole PHP-Page, where I send the Post request... No Errors...

Pls dont answer with "Use $.ajax" or "XML...". I want to use "$.post".

Comment: For example: Im Currently @ the Page "Test1" and want to send data to "Test2" with $.post. But the response is the whole HTML-Stuff from the Page "Test1". This is an example of my PHP-Code:         header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
        die(json_encode(array('message' => "okay")))

Comment: If you want to get contents specific in response to your request you should send a specific request. {id:idvalue} add an action key here.. like action : someAction, then in your php file put a check on this action.. like isset($_POST['someAction']) echo "something".. but in order to receive a json object from php file you need to make an array and json encode it first.

Comment: What i am trying to say is, you send a request to this file and in response it gets everything you have printed there. you should listen to the request and act in response accordingly.

Comment: If you had no idea about PHP than let me teach you... First: If you write an PHP-File (Test it on your own) and only got 2 Lines of Code (See my First Comment) you will get every Time the Same Respond (With any Kind of Parameters) Just try it out ;) Second: If I could Downvote your Comments, I would do.

Comment: That's what i have been saying all the way. Anyway if you can figure it out by your own, thats good. peace!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Answer.

I looked 1000 times but there are not a single PHP File with the same name, but I just renamed my PHP File 1-2 times to something completly Different from before and it worked... I dont know why, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Define *`some Erros`* if you think your answer could be valuable for future users or delete your answer and question.